# Can I safely use suspend/hibernate during an upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, suspend, hibernate

How will the upgrade progress react if I put the computer to sleep or hibernate it meanwhile upgrading? Right now it's downloading packages, if I close the lid, take the computer to work and start it up and connect it to another wireless network, will the process be cancelled?

**Update:**
Suspend and reconnect to a different network works fine during the package downloading process, but what about suspend meanwhile it installs packages or downloads the upgrade manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your edited question states, suspending does not usually cause a problem. You can minimize the already slim chances more by disconnecting from your internet connection so that the `apt` program can suspend the downloads gracefully.  There is always a chance that your computer may not suspend/hibernate correctly. If that happens, there is a chance that `apt` may lose track of the file it was downloading, likely the worst that that would cause would be having to restart that particular file again, so it's still only a small risk.

---

To answer your updated question, I would not suspend it while it is *installing* packages. Even on a good suspend and resume it might cause problems if you stopped it in the middle of updating important files, they might not install correctly.  If it crashed during the resume process, it would *very* likely cause partially installed packages, which can be recovered from, but it can be a headache that you can avoid by waiting a few minutes until the installation is complete.

As to the second part of your edit, I assume that by "Upgrade Manager" you are talking about upgrading your release, i.e. from 13.04 to 13.10.  Upgrading releases uses the `apt` program as well, it just downloads a lot more files before it installs them, so the answer is the same.  It is safe to suspend the download in the middle, but I would still disconnect the internet connection before shutting down/suspending.

The only difference is that it is *more* important to let the actual installation finish before shutting down, a partially installed distribution upgrade is much harder to recover from than a package upgrade; In a package upgrade you could just uninstall the package and reinstall it, but if you have 13.04 systems trying to boot with 13.10 files(for example) you could have a system that will not boot.  Again, you could still likely recover from that, but, it would be a lot more work.

To sum it up in one sentence, you should be safe suspending/shutting down during the file downloads, but I would not ***ever*** shut the computer down during the actual install of those files.  (Also I would not do it on battery power to avoid a low-power related shutdown)

Comment: By upgrade manager I refer to the first package the update manager downloads and installs before starting to downloading all of the packages.

Comment: @spydon, OK, thanks for the clarification, I don't think this changes anything in my answer, the upgrade manager would just be another package as far as `apt` is concerned.  Stopping the download should be fine but stopping it during the install is living dangerously...This would go for the downloads that the upgrade manager does as well, OK to stop(pause) the downloads but don't stop the install once it starts...

Comment: I suspend by Ubuntu 14.04 multiple times on a regular basis by mistake when the Software updater is doing some updates. I have not faced any issues till now. Whichever file was downloading at the time of suspend just continues after i turn it back on. If there were any update errors because of the suspend, i am yet to notice it.